# Python subprocess.run(). Combine all arguments into a single string?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

In Python 3.8, on Windows, I want to run this command from a Python script:

`openssl.exe req -out server2.csr -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout server2.priv.key -config server2.cnf`

Notice that it has 6 arguments. If you count each item separated by a space, there are 10 items after openssl.

The code below works, but it's very tedious. For every item that's separated by a space in the command, I have to separate it by quotes and commas in the code.

`subprocess.run(['openssl', 'req', '-out', 'server2.csr', '-newkey', 'rsa:4096', '-nodes', '-keyout', 'server2.priv.key', '-config', 'server2.cnf'])`

What I really want is something like this:

```
argument = 'req -out ' + servername + '.csr -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout ' + servername + '.priv.key -config ' + configfile
subprocess.run(['openssl', argument])
```

Is there a way in Python to combine all the arguments into one string? That way seems a lot easier to manage.

Comment: `subprocess.run(['openssl', *argument.split()])`

Comment: Try `subprocess.run(shlex.split(f'openssl req -out {servername}.csr -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout {servername}.priv.key -config {servername}.cnf'))`. We use `shlex.split()` (you have to `import shlex` of course) to handle the command splitting part. Also use f-string to make string formatting easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

how about using a combination of f-strings and string manipulation?

```
argument = f'req -out {servername}.csr -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout {servername}.priv.key -config {configfile}'
command =  f'openssl {argument}'.split(' ') # generate a list of space separated entries
subprocess.run([command])
```